# sed break into lines (advanced)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, command-line, grep

I'm looking to use `sed` (or combining it with another `grep` command)to convert the following string

```
John: Hi!,How are you,?,Dylan: Hey,OK
```

into

```
John: Hi!
John: How are you
John: ?
Dylan: Hey
Dylan: OK
```

If that's not possible I'm willing to compromise for

```
John: Hi!,How are you,?
Dylan: Hey,OK
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide a minimalistic code demo of what you have tried.

Comment: I tried too many things pretty messed the entire thing until you guys came to the rescue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` can be used.
There is a great [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-56) online page, which I always open aside when writing `sed` script.

Give a try to this:

```
printf 'John: Hi!,How are you,?,Dylan: Hey,OK\n' | sed -n '
:1
/./ {
  /^[^:,][^:,]*: / {
    h
    s/^\([^:,][^,:]*: \).*$/\1/
    x
    s/,/\n/
    P
    D
  }
  x
  /./ {
    x
    H
    x
    s/\n//g
    x
    s/.//g
    x
    b 1
  }
}'
```

The output is:

```
John: Hi!
John: How are you
John: ?
Dylan: Hey
Dylan: OK
```

Comment: Bravo! That is worth the UV just for the canny use of pattern and hold space and the lest oft used `D` to control the newline cycle.

Comment: I am BLOWN away! Thank you so much!

Comment: From my point of view both `/./ {` and the corresponding closing bracket `}` can be omitted.

Comment: @Cyrus This is true, this would give on one line:    

    `printf 'John: Hi!,How are you,?,Dylan: Hey,OK\n' | sed -n ':1 ; /^[^:,][^:,]*: / { h ; s/^\([^:,][^,:]*: \).*$/\1/ ; x ; s/,/\n/ ; P ; D } ; H ; x ; s/\n//g ; x ; s/.//g ; x ; b 1'`

Answer (score 3):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=","}{if($1~/:$/)p=$1;print ($1==p?"":p " ") $0}' file
John: Hi!
John: How are you
John: ?
Dylan: Hey
Dylan: OK
```

There will be an extra empty line in the end. For some awks (at least GNU awk, mawk and Busybox awk) you can use `RS="[,\n]"`.

Comment: I made the sed answer as correct because this didn't worked in my android in terms it made an extra line for "John" as part of "Dylan" line i.e. "John: Dylan: Hey"

Answer (score 2):

With `tr`and `awk`:

```
tr ',' '\n' <file | awk '/:/{name=$1; print; next}; {print name,$0}'
```

or shorter:

```
tr ',' '\n' <file | awk '/:/?name=$1:$0=name " " $0'
```

Output:

```
John: Hi!
John: How are you
John: ?
Dylan: Hey
Dylan: OK
```

Answer (score 1):

In single `awk`, considering that your Input_file is same as shown samples then following may help you here.

```
awk -F',' '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/:/){
      if($i ~ /: /){
        print $i
        split($i,array," ")
        val=array[1]
      }
      else{
        val=$i
      }
    }
    else{
      print val,$i
    }
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do something like this:

```
echo 'John: Hi!,How are you,?,Dylan: Hey,OK' | sed -E "s|(\w+:)|\n\1|g"
```

It will return:

```
John: Hi!,How are you,?,
Dylan: Hey,OK
```